# Python-Writing Decorators-Str is not Callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, decorator

I'm currently learning Python and have been at it for about six months. I've made a lot of progress and am now trying to wrap my head around decorators. I understand the general idea behind decorators and have written a handful of simple decorators in a basic format, but this time I am trying to write a function that can use a decorator more than once:

For example, the following:

```
def make_html(element):
    def wrapped(func, *args, **kwargs):
        return f'<{element}>' + func(*args, **kwargs) + f'</{element}>'
    return wrapped

@make_html('strong')
def get_text(text='I code in Python.'):
    return text

print(get_text)
```

Outputs this:

```
<strong>I code in Python.</strong>
```

However, if I actually call the function when I print:

```
print(get_text())
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/search and sort2.py", line 98, in <module>
    print(get_text())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Similarly, if I try to use the same decorator more than once on a function:

```
@make_html('p')
@make_html('strong')
def get_text(text='I code in Python.'):
    return text
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/search and sort2.py", line 94, in <module>
    def get_text(text='I code in Python.'):
  File "Local/Programs/Python/Python38/search and sort2.py", line 83, in wrapped
    return f'<{element}>' + func(*args, **kwargs) + f'</{element}>'
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong here? How can I use the same decorator more than once on a function, and why is my function being interpreted as a string?

Comment: Decorators with parameters need to be written differently - see the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! That link was helpful and I was able to figure out where I was going wrong. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help, and welcome to SO!